# How can I make the unique random numbers from this code appear on my page?

Tags: javascript, random

Someone showed me the following code which generates 3  random numbers between 1 and 10:

```
var limit = 10,
    amount = 3,
    lower_bound = 1,
    upper_bound = 10,
    unique_random_numbers = [];

if (amount > limit) limit = amount; //Infinite loop if you want more unique
                                    //Natural numbers than exist in a
                                    // given range
while (unique_random_numbers.length < limit) {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper_bound - lower_bound) + lower_bound);
    if (unique_random_numbers.indexOf(random_number) == -1) { 
        // Yay! new random number
        unique_random_numbers.push( random_number );
    }
}
//
```

**How could I make these numbers appear in place of elements with a corresponding class?** The code below is clearly wrong, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var random_number1 = random_number1(); 
    $('.random_number1').html(random_number1);

    var random_number2 = random_number2(); 
    $('.random_number2').html(random_number2);
</script>

<span class="random_number1"></span>  <span class = "random_number2"></span>
```

Comment: your random number generator is overly complicated by the way :p and yes, your attempt is clearly wrong. You have an array of unique_random_numbers ... use it, rather than the non-existent functions randum_number1/2

Comment: "Someone" is wrong. That code doesn't generate 3 random numbers between 1 and 10, it generates a non-responsive page thanks to an infinite loop. It's trying to generate 10 unique random integers in [1, 9].

Comment: well your code also references elements before it exists on the page.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the code above to correct an issue that I'm having with "tail recursivity" in my existing code. I'll post my existing code to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you had a div with id of numbers and the array unique_random_numbers, you'd populate it this way, assuming you have jquery reference:

```
for ( i = 0; i < unique_random_numbers.length; i++)
{
    $("#Numbers").html($("#Numbers").html() +"<span>" + unique_random_numbers[i] + "</span><br/>");
}
```